# How to complete challenge 2 of Knight Squad?

Tags: knight-squad

In the challenge section of Knight Squad, I cannot complete the second challenge. (Which is where you have to kill all 4 worms) I hit the tails of the worms to make them curl up, but then nothing happens and I just eventually die. I have no idea how to complete this challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bit more, I found that the worms die after a set amount of hits. What I was confused about before was that nothing actually happens until they die, so not killing any of them meant that nothing happened. When they do die, they explode  into a skeleton.

[image: Knight Squad]